# CrystalReport Suppress Page Number is section is empty

Tags: crystal-reports

I have re-designing a report inside the Visual Studio 2010 Crystal Report Designer.
I have this structure

```
Report Header
    Page Header
       Details Section
         Section1
         Section2
         Section3
         Section4
         Section5
    Page Footer
Report Footer
```

Every Section is hide if empty.

My proble is that if I put page number field inside the PageFooter, the section are never empty and the section is show as a white page.

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Do you mean when there's no data at all?

Comment: I mean: whene the section is hide couse of empty

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set the section to suppress conditionally based on a formula rather than "if empty". What other fields do you have in your page footer?

Comment: Currently, I have no other fields.

Comment: i'm a bit confused what you're trying to do then? when do you want the page footer (with page number) to display? and when do you want to suppress it?

Comment: Try suppressing the page footer with the formula: `count({mytable.myfield}) = 0' replace the field with any field from your dataset

Answer (score 0):

Use a suppress formula instead.

```
RecordCount = 0
```